# How can I decrease the default looking time of a WebElement in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Web Element in a webpage that is present in 5th or 6th frame.  So I made a for loop to look for the WebElement in each frame from index '0' to 'total number of frames'.  However, Selenium Webdriver takes more time(more than 60 second) to check for the WebElement in each frame.  Is there any method/way to decrease the time, the webdriver checks on each frame.  If I could have a method like check for the WebElement is present for 5 seconds, if not, go to next frame, it would be useful.

Comment: Your code trials and the relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: It should not take that long, are you using `implicitlywait` and setting it too high? It would be helpful if you added what @DebanjanB is asking for. Code please.